# Iron Python, Can't find a file

Tags: ironpython

I've been trying to get Iron Python to reference a file but it seems it can't find it or recognize it. I started with this command and received an error message.

I'm aware of the problems with the backslashes in windows so I moved on to some experiments that are listed after this error message.

sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\Bosch Sensortec\Development Desktop 2.0\UserpApplicationBoard")

clr.AddReference('UserApplicationBoard.dll')

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 1, in 
>   IOError: System.IO.IOException: Could not add reference to assembly > > >UserApplicationBoard.dll
>     at IronPython.Runtime.ClrModule.AddReference(CodeContext context, String >name)
>     at IronPython.Runtime.ClrModule.AddReference(CodeContext context, Object[] >references)
>     at >Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame >frame)
>     at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
>     at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](T0 >arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
>     at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite >site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
>     at >IronPython.Compiler.Ast.CallExpression.Invoke1Instruction.Run(InterpretedFrame >frame)
>     at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
>     at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 >arg1)
>     at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
>     at IronPython.Hosting.PythonCommandLine.<>c__DisplayClass1. 
>   b__0()

So I tested the path, which seems to work but when I try the file is says it doesn't exist. I tried it several ways with backslashes, double backslashes and forward slashes.

> > > os.path.exists('C:\Program Files\Bosch Sensortec\Development Desktop 2.0\UserpApplicationBoard')
> > >       True
> > >
> > > os.path.isfile('C:\Program Files\Bosch Sensortec\Development Desktop >2.0\UserApplicationBoard.dll')
> > >       False
> > >
> > > os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files\\Bosch Sensortec\\Development Desktop 2.0')
> > >       True
> > >
> > > os.path.isfile('C:\\Program Files\\Bosch Sensortec\\Development Desktop 2.0\\UserApplicationBoard.dll')
> > >       False
> > >
> > > os.path.isfile('C:/Program Files/Bosch Sensortec/Development Desktop 2.0/UserApplicationBoard.dll')
> > >       False

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I found a way to make it work. I moved the file from my Program Files (x86) directory to C:\UAB\

This worked...

os.path.isfile('c:\\UAB\\UserApplicationBoard.dll')
TRUE

It may have has something to do with the (x86) directory or the path itself. 

Thanks